# Qt Cannot open file 'sqlite3.lib'

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I downloaded official Database for SQLite project from [GitHub](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser). I tried to compile this project but I received an error: "Cannot open file 'sqlite3.lib'".

I'm using Qt 5.6.0.

Compile output:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'sqlite3.lib'
jom: C:\Users\loddy\Desktop\sqDebug\src\Makefile.Debug [debug\sqlitebrowser.exe] Error 1104
jom: C:\Users\loddy\Desktop\sqDebug\src\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\loddy\Desktop\sqDebug\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
20:11:18: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project sqlitebrowser (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 MSVC2015 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Also, there are sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h files in project.

What should I do for solve this problem?

Comment: The question is, what do you want exactly to achieve? Do you only want to access sqlite databases? If yes, Qt already has the plugin to access the SQlite (it comes with standart Qt instalation).

Answer (score 1):

Qt has the ability to access SQLite databases. You could write code like this:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <qDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("test.db");
    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << db.lastError();
        qFatal("failed to connect database.");
    }
    qDebug() << "database connected";

    QString sql = QString("insert into tb_test values('John', 10)");
    qDebug() << "sql: " << sql;

    QSqlQuery query(sql, db); // query will be automatically executed if sql is not an empty string, see Qt document for details

    return a.exec();
}
```

In above code, I asume that the database `test.db` has one table called `tb_test`. And it has two fields, `name`, which is varchar, and `age`, which is int.

Please make sure that you have Sql module loaded in your project.

FYI, [Online Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html), or you could search by class names in Qt Assistant, which is installed by Qt on your computer.